# IBM WAS ignoring security in web.xml

Tags: java, security, websphere, web.xml

i have working web application for tomcat web server. I want to migrate it to IBM websphere AS but im stuck at security problem.
Whole app security is defined in web.xml file like this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list> 

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Dynamic pages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>access.</description>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config id="LoginConfig_1">
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>SecureRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config id="FormLoginConfig_1">
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginFail.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <description>User of the application.</description>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Websphere ignore all this security and allow me to access any page from web app without showing login page. If i go manually to login.jsp and put correct password im forwarded into app but then it fail on `getUserPrincipal()` because it return null (no login). Also same if i put wrong password im forwarded to loginFail.jsp. 
Also no error in server logs. 
What am i doing wrong or is different from tomcat?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WebSphere security may not be enabled. If it's not, your web.xml settings will be ignored.

In the admin console, look in the Security -> Global Security section. Make sure 'Enable application security' is checked.

Note that you can create different security settings at different 'levels' (node, server, etc). If you have multiple domains defined in Security -> Security Domains, make sure the app server your webapp is running on has the correct domain set.

Comment: It is also worth to mention that after enabling security you need to restart the server.